# Import Word Documents (docx) to OneNote 2013/2016

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, import, microsoft-onenote-2013, microsoft-onenote-2016

Is it possible to import word documents (docx) to OneNote without printing every single word document to onenote?

The import should create a onenote page for each word document.

Answer (score 0):

Open your document in word and print it to OneNote. It should import your word document into OneNote without doing every word document. This at present seems to be the only way to do it.

Comment: i dont want to print every document because the printout is only a image

Comment: You can also try the simple copy / paste method.

Comment: i'm lazy, thats why i asked the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Use "Send to OneNote" to import MS Office components directly to OneNote.

This is available in OneNote 2013 at the bottom in a special "notes" portion:

[image: ScreenShot]

See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mh808blm1Ok) for further details

Answer (score 0):

After some trial, I found the method below works:

1. Save the Word document as an HTML file
2. Copy the contents in the HTML file into OneNote. Both images and text will be copied.